# <Redirect /> doesn't work when I separate the routes into other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The problem is that when entering a route that does not exist the  does not work, this only happens when I separate the / login and / register routes in another component, is there any way to solve it? Thanks for reading

AppRouter.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Switch,
    Link,
    Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom'

import JournalScreen from '../screens/JournalScreen'
import AuthRoutes from './AuthRoutes'

export default function AppRouter() {
    return (
        <Router>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/noexists">no exists</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/register">register</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/login">login</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <Switch>

                <Route exact path="/" component={JournalScreen} />
                
                <AuthRoutes />

                <Redirect to="/" />

            </Switch>

        </Router>
    )
}
```

AuthRoutes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen'
import RegisterScreen from '../screens/RegisterScreen'

export default function AuthRouter() {
    return (

        <div className="app__auth">

            <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} />

            <Route path="/register" component={RegisterScreen} />

        </div>


    )
}
```

Comment: To understand your question better, just wanted to confirm, do you want to redirect the user to `/` when the user tries to access a path that is not valid right?

Comment: @AsitPrakash yess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution:

AppRouter.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Switch,
    Link,
    Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom'

import JournalScreen from '../screens/JournalScreen'
import AuthRoutes from './AuthRoutes'

export default function AppRouter() {
    return (
        <Router>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/noexists">no exists</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/register">register</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/login">login</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <Switch>

                <Route exact path="/" component={JournalScreen} />

                <AuthRoutes />

                <Redirect to="/" />

            </Switch>

        </Router>
    )
}
```

AuthRoutes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen'
import RegisterScreen from '../screens/RegisterScreen'

export default function AuthRoutes() {

    return (

        <div className="app__auth">

            <Switch>

                <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} />

                <Route path="/register" component={RegisterScreen} />

                <Redirect to="/" />

            </Switch>

        </div>


    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [react router docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch):

```
<Switch>

Renders the first child <Route> or <Redirect> that matches the location.
```

So, your `Route` components have to be direct children of `Switch` in order to work properly.
This can be solved by using fragments in your `AuthRouter` component

```
export default function AuthRouter() {
  return (
    <>
      <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Route path="/register" component={RegisterScreen} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Another thing to note is that all react-router functions will only work in elements that are a child of a `Router` component. So if you have another component that is *not* a child of `AppRouter`, you won't be able to use any of react-router's capabilities

Most commonly, wrapping your entire app in a single `Router` component is the way to go. This is also taken from the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/primary-components/routers):

```
To use a router, just make sure it is rendered at the root of your element
hierarchy. Typically you’ll wrap your top-level <App> element in a router
```

Comment: The <redirect /> still does not work, it only works when everything is in the AppRouter, I find it very strange that it cannot be separated